# Get Maximum from column with Python in Databricks notebook

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

I use DataBricks as a service on Azure. I need to get maximum value of one field by Python. I wrote below code but I am wondering if there is another way to get max number without Loop.

```
%python 
SqlMaxValue ="""select  IFNULL(MAX(Id) , 0) AS Max_ID
                FROM {0}.t_xxxx""".format(gvDB_xxxx)
DF_SqlMaxValue = spark.sql(SqlMaxValue)
MaxAttr = ''

for y in DF_SqlMaxValue.collect():    
      MaxAttr = y.Max_ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Maximum from column with Python in Databricks notebook:

```
dataframe.agg({"Column": "max"}).collect()[0]
```

**OR**

To get a particular column's MAX value of a dataframe can be determined using this:

```
max_value = df.agg({"any-column": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
```

**Example:** I had a list of players with the scores associated in the last cricket worldcup. To get the maximum number from the specific column named Run

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this code will return only one row with one column, so the code could be written as:

```py
MaxAttr = DF_SqlMaxValue.first()[0]
```

the `first` is returning first row of the dataframe, and `[0]` fetches the value of first column...